# Enforcing desired CompletableFuture behavior

Tags: java, completable-future

I'm playing with CompletableFuture chains and stumbled upon a situation with unexpected behavior (for me, at least): if an exceptional CompletableFuture is passed in `.thenCompose()` call, the resulting CompletableFuture will be finished with original exception wrapped in `CompletionException`. It may be hard to understand without an example:

```
public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> exceptional(Throwable error) {
    CompletableFuture<T> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    future.completeExceptionally(error);
    return future;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletableFuture<Void> exceptional = exceptional(new RuntimeException());
    exceptional
            .handle((result, throwable) -> {
                System.out.println(throwable);
                // java.lang.RuntimeException

                System.out.println(throwable.getCause());
                // null

                return null;
            });

    CompletableFuture
            .completedFuture(null)
            .thenCompose(v -> exceptional)
            .handle((result, throwable) -> {
                System.out.println(throwable);
                // java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException

                System.out.println(throwable.getCause());
                // java.lang.RuntimeException

                return null;
            });
}
```

Of course i was expecting to deal with the same `RuntimeException` no matter how many transformations were before or after in chain. I have two questions:

- Is it expected behavior?
- Do i have any options to keep original exception passed through except for manual unwrapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaDoc for [`thenCompose()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenCompose-java.util.function.Function-) is:

> Returns a new CompletionStage that, when this stage completes normally, is executed with this stage as the argument to the supplied function. See the [`CompletionStage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html) documentation for rules covering exceptional completion.

and the definition of the interface states:

> […] In all other cases, if a stage's computation terminates abruptly with an (unchecked) exception or error, then all dependent stages requiring its completion complete exceptionally as well, with a [`CompletionException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionException.html) holding the exception as its cause. […]

As `thenCompose` returns a dependent stage, **this is expected behavior**.

In fact, the only cases in which you could have something else than a `CompletionException` is when you complete a `CompletableFuture` explicitly with methods like `completeExceptionally()`, `cancel()` etc. Even methods such as `supplyAsync()` will wrap your exceptions.

I don't think there is any other option to access the original exception as it is already quite easy to unwrap it with `getCause()`. If you really need to do that often, you could write a helper method such as:

```
public static <T, U> BiFunction<? super T, Throwable, ? extends U>
        unwrappingCompletionException(BiFunction<? super T, Throwable, ? extends U> fn) {
    return (t, u) -> {
        if (u instanceof CompletionException) {
            return fn.apply(t, u.getCause());
        }
        return fn.apply(t, u);
    };
}
```

and use it as follows:

```
CompletableFuture
        .completedFuture(null)
        .thenCompose(v -> exceptional)
        .handle(unwrappingCompletionException((result, throwable) -> {
            […]
        }));
```